# How to code a single Neuron that predicts marks in Java

Tags: java, neural-network

I just started with neural networks and thanks to absolute terrible lecturing with no example we are left in the dark with the task to create a single neuron that will take as input 3 marks of different subjects and predict the student's mark for another subject.

We are given historical data to train our neuron which consist of 3 marks and the actual mark. I somewhat understand the concepts of how the process work: Input each mark with initial random weight, apply linear activation function and then update the weight. However I am clueless as to what this looks like in code or how exactly the neuron class is constructed. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Did the neural networks class have no prerequisite topics? I assume there's always a general programming courses before? Your question sounds like there weren't any.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the recommended textbook for the course.  (I recall ... back in the day ... doing undergraduate courses where the lectures were so hopeless, I resorted to learning from the text books instead of the lectures.  Just used the lectures as a guide as to what to read.)

Comment: Very basic introduction a year ago yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single neuron within a neural network acts precisely like a logistic regression model.
So, for the purposes of this answer, I am going to assume your question is 'how do I apply LR?'

Let's start with the training. The model (like a neural network) is trained in iterations.

```
public void train(double[][] xs, double[] ys)
{
    if(xs.length != ys.length)
        return;
    if(xs.length == 0)
        return;

    int N = xs[0].length;

    // init coefficients
    if(coefficients == null)
        coefficients = new double[N];

    // start training
    double c0 = cost(xs, ys);
    for(int i=0;i<nofEpochs;i++)
    {
        // execute one epoch of training
        epoch(xs, ys);
        double c1 = cost(xs, ys);

        // quit if cost becomes higher
        if(c1 > c0)
            break;

        c0 = c1;

        // print debug output
        if(isDebugEnabled)
            System.out.println("epoch : " + i + "\tcost : " + c1);
    }

}
```

Let's break that down.
First we do some basic sanity checks.
xs represents the input(s), ys represents the single output.
Obviously we want there to be equal number of rows in xs and ys.

If there are zero rows, we are not going to bother doing any work.

Then we initialize the coefficients (these are the weights of the connections in the neural network)

then we call the main loop, which will run for as many iterations as desired (or until no improvement is made)

This look simply calls the code for `epoch` and then calculates the cost.
If the cost has not gone down, no further iterations are done. You can of course change this rather brutal stopping criterium.

```
private void epoch(double[][] xs, double[] ys)
{
    int N = xs.length;
    int M = xs[0].length;

    // calculate gradient
    double[] gradient = new double[M];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
            gradient[j] += costDerivative(xs[i], ys[i], coefficients,j);
    }

    // normalize
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        gradient[i] /= N;
    }

    // apply
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        coefficients[i] -= (gradient[i] * learningRate);
    }
}
```

This code represents one epoch. It calculates the gradient for each coefficient (aka weight), aggregates the updates over the entire training set, normalizes the total, and updates the coefficients accordingly.

Finally, we need the definition of the derivative of the cost function.
I opted for a numeric approach (this means I avoid the complexity of forcing the user to input the derivative of a cost function every time he/she changes the cost function)

```
private double costDerivative(double[] x, double y, double[] cfs, int i)
{
    double delta = 0.00001;

    cfs[i] -= delta;
    double c0 = cost(x, y, cfs);

    cfs[i] += (delta * 2.0);
    double c1 = cost(x, y, cfs);

    return (c1 - c0) / (delta * 2.0);
}
```

This numeric approach simply estimates the derivative by calculating the cost slightly before, and slightly after the requested x-value.

The clever thing about neural networks (if we are talking about multiple neurons and layers) is that these calculations can be re-written to use matrices. Which of course speeds everything up (and can be paralleled and GPU-offloaded)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!